# Generic form of this function of factorization

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Every positive integer $n$ has a unique factorization $2^l \cdot m$, consider $f(n) = l + m$. Is there a closed-form of $f(n)$ based on $n$ where $l$ is nonnegative integer and $m$ is a positive odd integer.

I broke this into cases.

I found that for odd numbers $f(n) = n$

For powers of $2$, it is just $f(n) = \log_2(n) + 1$

I am unable to find it for even numbers that aren't power of $2$. Any advice?

Comment: Do you mean just a single closed form definition of  function for all the positive numbers or just for the remaining ones? The remaining ones are even numbers which are not a power of two...please clarify.

Comment: Also note that $ f(6) = 4, f(10)=6, f(12)=5, f(14) = 8, f(18) = 10, f(20)=9, f(22)=12, f(24)=6 ...$ doesn't look like any straight forward function is going to fit over that.

Comment: I suppose that in the mentioned  factorisation, $m$ is *odd*.

Comment: @Bernard,,, yes

Answer (score 1):

Denoting $v_2(n)$ the  dyadic valuation of $n$, i.e. the exponent of $2$ in the prime powers decomposition of $n$, you can  write
$$f(n)=v_2(n)+\frac n{2^{v_{2}(n)}}.$$